# Resources for human anatomy

Tags: research, health-education, anatomy

What are *preferably free and preferably PDF filetype* online resources that one can use to study the basic anatomy of the human body?

### Disclaimer

I feel like these would be great for Health.SE as we could provide a link to those resources that everyone can access instead of books that are usually very costly. I'm starting with human anatomy because this seems the most important to me.

Comment: This might also be suited for [meta], but I think Health.SE is the better place for the question... Feel free to argue about it with me though, I'm open to suggestions ;)

Comment: Wedged in among these Internet Archive books on pharmacology is a book on anatomy and physiology. All the books are pretty recent I believe. Book selection no. 2. is anatomy, I have not read this book, but it may be of interest to someone:  https://archive.org/details/AnatomyByGerardJ.TortoraBryanH.Derrickson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **[TeachMeAnatomy](http://teachmeanatomy.info/)**

> Containing over 700 vibrant, full-colour images, TeachMeAnatomy is a comprehensive anatomy encyclopedia presented in a visually-appealing, easy-to-read format.
>
> Created by a team of doctors and medical students, each topic combines anatomical knowledge with high-yield clinical pearls, seamlessly bridging the gap between scholarly learning and improved patient care.

This is a good site which mainly deals with anatomy of the human body, It also freely accessible and which can also be considered credible. Also see the **[TeachMeSeries](https://teachmeseries.com/)** which contains information about other fields of medicine.

- **[Medscape](http://reference.medscape.com/guide/anatomy)**

> Medscape is the leading online global destination for physicians and healthcare professionals worldwide, offering the latest medical news and expert perspectives; essential point-of-care drug and disease information; and relevant professional education and CME.

- **[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/health-and-medicine/human-anatomy-and-physiology)**

> Get introduced to the major organ systems of the human body! You’ll learn some general anatomy (a roadmap of your body), learn how the arm bone actually connects to the shoulder bone, and how the different organs work together to keep you alive. Watch some videos, read some articles, try some flashcards, and then quiz yourself!

- **[These bones of mine](https://thesebonesofmine.wordpress.com/skeletal-basics/)**

> This blog will explicitly introduce the human skeleton and its anatomical traits to a general and interested audience.
>
> This blog then is an introduction and a repository for me, detailing my interests in the field and whilst also documenting my own ongoing archaeological experience.  Furthermore, I want to take you on a journey of discovery of self learning by detailing what exactly human osteologists and bioarchaeologists do.  Alongside this approach I will also include details of my own extensive experience of bone disease.
>
> Up to date academic references are noted on each post explicitly and an effort is made to find an Open Access articles and resources, where available, as appropriate.  Within each of these references you will find much more detail on the specific subject highlighted and also on the practice of human osteology and archaeology in general.  Please enjoy and share.

- **PDFs**

  • [The Anatomy](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43350)

  > This discusses about the anatomy of human peritonium and abdominal cavity.[[From: Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:Bookshelf)] which contains many other free access books related to other field also.

  • [Surgical Anatomy](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/24440) [From: Project Gutenberg]

  • [Anatomy and Physiology](https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/BookDetail.aspx?bookId=169) [From: Open Textbook Library]

  • [The organisation of the Retina and Visual System](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11530/?term=%22anatomy%20and%20histology%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D%20OR%20(%22anatomy%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D%20AND%20%22histology%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D)%20OR%20%22anatomy%20and%20histology%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D%20OR%20%22anatomy%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D%20OR%20%22anatomy%22%5BAll%20Fields%5D) [From: [NCBI Bookshelf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books)]

  • [[Anatomy By Gerard J. Tortora, Bryan H. Derrickson](https://archive.org/stream/AnatomyByGerardJ.TortoraBryanH.Derrickson/anatomy%20by%20Gerard%20J.%20Tortora%2C%20Bryan%20H.%20Derrickson#page/n4/mode/1up)] (Thanks to @[Gordon](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/13819/gordon))

Comment: +1: Thank you very much! What about PDF resources? Like textbooks in PDF format.

Comment: YW, I will check and add it, if you are interested in textbooks , you can visit Google books, but the problem is the best books are not free.

Comment: @Narusan, why PDF?

Comment: @Jan Because PDFs can be opened by everyone everywhere, and text can be extracted easily. I guess html sites would also work

Answer (score 4):

[Gray's Anatomy](http://www.bartleby.com/107/) - an old but complete online book with detailed text and pictures.

[Get Body Smart](https://www.getbodysmart.com/) - by organic systems, at a glance

[Inner Body](http://www.innerbody.com/image/musfov.html) - on hover interactive images, with text

[KenHub](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kenhub%20anatomy) - 50 videos

[AnatomyZone](http://anatomyzone.com/tutorials-page/) - ~200 videos, including basic terminology